# How to store a function name in JSON?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a React app. There are components rendered from mapped data like the following:

```
function App () {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(1);
  const cardDetails = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'card 1',
      setPrice: setPrice
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'card 2',
      setPrice: setPrice
    }
  ]

  const renderCards = (cardDetails) => {
    return (
      cardDetails.map((c) => {
        <Card cardData={c} />
      })
    )
  };
  return (
    <>
      {renderCards(cardDetails)}
    </>
  )
}
```

It's working well. Now I'd like to move the `cardDetails` data into a JSON file. I defined the following `cardDetails.js`:

```
export const cardDetails = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'card 1',
      setPrice: setPrice
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'card 2',
      setPrice: setPrice
    }
  ]
```

However, I can't pass function `setPrice` in the JSON file, any idea what I could do to use the external JSON file?

Comment: What happens when you try to pass the `setPrice` to the JSON file? And why do you want to pass `setPrice` to a JSON file, seems dubious.

Comment: *"Now I'd like to move the `cardDetails` data into a JSON file. I defined the following `cardDetails.js`"* That's not JSON. It's just JavaScript in a separate file. Is that what you want, or do you really want JSON?

Comment: More: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I would suggest you store your function name as a string in the JSON and call the function dynamically using the syntax like `object[function_name_in_string_from_json]()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just want to use a separate file to store data, JSON, JS, all good

Comment: Side note: `return (<>{renderCards(cardDetails)}</>)` can be simply `return renderCards(cardDetails);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `setPrice` function only exists in `App`, it can't be in the separate file. You asked *"How to store a function name in JSON?"* and while you *could* do that (`setPrice: "setPrice"`, and then when mapping the cards replace it with the `setPrice` function), it doesn't really buy you anything.

But it's simple to have `App` add it to the cards as it's passing them to the `Card` component: `<Card cardData={{ ...c, setPrice }} />` That uses spread syntax to spread out the object from `c` into a new object and adds `setPrice` to the new object.

To avoid creating new objects on every render (which might force `Card` to re-render unnecessarily, if `Card` is memoized), we can use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to memoize the array of extended cards like this:

```
const fullCards = useMemo(() => (
    cardDetails.map((card) => ({...card, setPrice}))
), [cardDetails]);
```

...and then use `fullCards` for the `map`.

Full version:

In `cardDetails.js`:

```
export const cardDetails = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "card 1",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "card 2",
    },
];
```

Your component:

```
import { cardDetails } from "./cardDetails.js";

function App() {
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(1);
    const fullCards = useMemo(() => (
        cardDetails.map((card) => ({...card, setPrice}))
    ), [cardDetails]);

    const renderCards = (cardDetails) => cardDetails.map((c) => {
        <Card key={c.id} cardData={c} />;
    });
    return renderCards(fullCards);
}
```

Or simply:

```
function App() {
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(1);
    const fullCards = useMemo(() => (
        cardDetails.map((card) => ({...card, setPrice}))
    ), [cardDetails]);

    return fullCards.map((c) => {
        <Card key={c.id} cardData={c} />;
    });
}
```

Note that I added the `key` prop to the `Card` elements. You need a key on elements in arrays; details in the React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

---

That would also work just fine if you wanted to store the data in a JSON file like:

```
[
    {
        "id:: 1,
        "title": "card 1",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "card 2",
    },
]
```

...and then load and parse that JSON for use in `App`.